# JPA get SQL query parameters

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm using OpenJpa in a Java web project and I'm struggling with getting the SQL queries and the SQL parameters out of a JPQL query. So far I could get only the SQL queries using something like:

```
openJPAQuery.compile();
String[] sqls= openJPAQuery.getDataStoreActions(null);
```

The SQL queries can contain parameters, even though the original JPQL query has none. My problem is how do I get the list of SQL parameters, in order to make a plain JDBC call to database?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why are you doing that instead of just letting JPA execute the query, or use JDBC directly, with your own query?

Comment: @JBNizet It's a performance issue. The JPA query is used to fill in a huge report. Because JPA query result list is all-in-memory, I get an out-of -memory error. By executing the SQL query instead, I can cycle through ResultSet without retaining all records in memory.

Comment: Have you read and tried using this, instead: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#ref_guide_dbsetup_lrs? Or just using JDBC directly rather than trying to get the SQL query from a JPQL query?

Comment: @JBNizet The first thing to try was that on the link. It's not working. The used memory is somewhat smaller, but not enough and the execution time is way too big. Using JDBC directly is not that easy because the SQL query must by a dynamic one (there is an user filter and a security filter). Right now it is implemented using Jpa Criteria API. Not to mention that I have about 10 such reports.

Comment: Generating SQL queries is not that hard. And tools like QueryDSL can do it for you. Frankly, that sounds like a much better option than doing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet I can't add new library to the project, that's the problem. QueryDSL is working like a charm here.